# iPhone development: play animation backwards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

In my app there is an animation. when I press a button the animation (lets say a box moves from the left to the right.) is performed and the ViewController is changed by "pushViewContreller". What I want is when I use popViewController from the secondViewController, the firstViewController should be opened and the box should move from right to left(reverse action). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to reverse a navigation controllers native view changing animations?

Answer (score 0):

Before navigate , save START position and END position of box, and when you come back then move box from END position to START position.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move a box then you can use this code.
First of all make two CGRect say CGRect left and CGRect right.

then in viewWillAppear of firstViewController write this code.

```
        CGRect left = //Your left side Frame
        CGRect right = //Your right side frame
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(right, YourObject.center))
        {

             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

                 [YourObject setFrame:left];

             }];
        }
```

In this code viewWillAppear will call every time you when you pop secondViewController and if your box will be on right it will make animation of taking it to left.

on button click write this code

```
        CGRect left = //Your left side Frame
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

             [YourObject setFrame:left];

        }];
```

Hope you will be happy after using this code........